# Azure Data Factory Copy Activity fails converting MongoDB ISODate to DateTime v2 connector

Tags: sql-server, mongodb, azure, azure-data-factory

I am running into an issue with the MongoDB V2 connector in the Copy Activity. Converting an ISODate() field in MongoDB to a SQL Stored Procedure fails with the following error

```
Column 'createdAt' contains an invalid value '1578842185255'. Cannot convert '1578842185255' to type 'DateTime'.
```

<strike>It very much feels like a **.net error** and not an issue with SQL at all</strike>

We've been running Copy Pipelines for more than a year with the **MongoDB V1 connector** and never had this issue

We're using MongoDB 3.6, DataFactory v2 and SQL Server on Azure

Anyone running into this?

Updates:
I found a work around by having the sql table type / stored procedure accepting a `bigint` and then converting the timestamp to a date in SQL

Question remains is why the data factory broke this functionality with the V2 Connector

Answer (score 0):

V1 connector used a different protocol to get data from MongoDB but V2 connector is using a different driver to get the original data from MongoDB. That was the reason you are seeing a difference between V1 and V2 connectors.

If you have any feedback/suggestion regarding this connector, I would recommend you to please share it ADF uservoice forum. All the feedback shared in this forum will be actively monitored and reviewed by ADF engineering team.

ADF uservoice forum: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-azure-data-factory

Reference: The same topic was discussed in MSDN forum: [Copy Activity fails converting MongoDB ISODate to DateTime v2 connector](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/aa0ea926-9b97-4324-89c9-134179cdf37d/copy-activity-fails-converting-mongodb-isodate-to-datetime-v2-connector?forum=AzureDataFactory)